# How to query hierachical data that are not based on document IDs but on another property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Lets say I have hierarchical structure of comments like this:

```
Comment 1
   Comment 2
   Comment 3
      Comment 4
```

That is represented using following sequence of events stored as documents in mongodb:

```
Id  EventType       ContentId   ParentContentId
1   CommentAdded    1   
2   CommentEdited   1   
3   CommentAdded    2           1
4   CommentAdded    3           1
5   CommentUpvoted  3
6   CommentAdded    4           3
```

Is it possible to query the hierarchy based on root ContentId as following:

```
getCommentsTree(rootContentId) { … }
var comments = getCommentsTree(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

References: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/index.html and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#pipe._S_graphLookup.

The idea is to filter out (`match` operator) the requested document and then use the `graphLookup` aggregate function (check all the limitations, such as max memory)

```
db.getCollection('comments').aggregate([
{
    $match : { "ContentId" : 1.0 } 
},
{
   $graphLookup: {
      from: 'comments',
      startWith: "$ContentId",
      connectFromField: "ContentId",
      connectToField: "ParentContentId",
      as: "hierarchy"
   }
}])
```

This will return the object that matched with an added hierarchy array, showing all descendants, something like this:

```
...
"hierarchy" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "type" : "added",
        "text" : "c3",
        "parentId" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 4,
        "type" : "added",
        "text" : "c4",
        "parentId" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "type" : "added",
        "text" : "c2",
        "parentId" : 1
    }
]

...
"hierarchy" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "type" : "added",
        "text" : "c3",
        "parentId" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 4,
        "type" : "added",
        "text" : "c4",
        "parentId" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "type" : "added",
        "text" : "c2",
        "parentId" : 1
    }
]
```

You should have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/ to see if other modeling techniques would be better for your scenario.